# what will happen when addSubView a big view into a small View

Tags: iphone, uiview

There is a xib with a a dark view (called `calendarView`) in it

[image]

Next is I am adding a subView called `calendar` ( this is a calendar view from this [page](http://tapku.com/) )

```
[self.calendarView addSubview:calendar];
```

And the result is :the `calendar` is added but it is cover the `calendarView`

[image]

My question :

1. what will happen when you try to add a bigger view into a small view.
2. How to make a bigger view fit in the the small view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general the subview will draw itself bigger then the superview. if you dont want that to happen you should set the subview's frame to smaller or equal to the superview's bounds.
if the subview is a costume class you made, you should probably change it to be in the right size, otherwise I think the best way to do it is with transform

Comment: I think @ttran wants to use the smaller view to cover the bigger one. see the calendar? - the bigger view? So I guess he wants to hide/show the calendar by increasing/decreasing the smaller view's size. if so, it's ok, just one thing: he must set the bigger view not to autoresize itself when the smalles view is changing its size, as it is his paren one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Nothing exceptional. The bigger view will be placed accordingly to it's frame.
2. Simple, just by equaling their sizes (and the added view's origin to be (0,0) ).